# How to check background inline exits or not

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to check that the div has background inline style or not.

**html**

```
<div style="background: #000"> </div>
<div style="background-image: url(image.jpg);"></div>
<div style="background-position: 0 0;"></div>
<div style="color: #000"></div>
```

If inline background style exits add class "test".

If inline background-image style exits then add class "test-1".

Comment: `$("div").attr("style") != null && $("div").attr("style").indexOf("background-XXXX:") >= 0`

Comment: check only if background-image exists or not.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
if($("div[style*='background']")){
  //exist...!!! now addclass to these elements
  $("div[style*='background']").addClass('test');
  $("div[style*='background-image']").addClass('test-1');
}
```

Comment: Hi
Also check, 
If inline background-image style exits then add class "test-1".

Answer (score 0):

you can check using `css()`

```
$("div").each(function () {

console.log($(this).css("background-image"));

if ($(this).css("background-image") != "none") 
   $(this).addClass("test")
})
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/tSq67/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var o =  $('div').filter(function(){
          return $(this).attr('style').indexOf('background') !== -1;
    }).length;

    alert(o);
```